# PostgreSQL Numeric Field Overflow Error - A field with precision 10, scale 1 must round to an absolute value less than 10^9

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-12

Please I'm trying to find the percentage difference between two values sum of imls2016.visits and sum of imls2010.visits in each row. Which was previously working fine before I added a third table in my joint statement (the table being imls_regions). But anytime I run the new code it throws a numeric overflow error. I have adjusted the precision and scale but I haven't been able to rectify this error. Please what should I change in my code:
(PostgreSQL 12)

- Error Message: > "ERROR:  numeric field overflow
  DETAIL:  A field with precision 10, scale 1 must round to an absolute value less than 10^9.
  SQL state: 22003"

My code:

```
SELECT imlsreg.obereg,
        imlsreg.obereg_name,
        SUM(imls2016.visits) AS total_visits_2016,
        SUM(imls2010.visits) AS total_visits_2010,
        ROUND((CAST(SUM(imls2016.visits) AS decimal(10, 1)) - SUM(imls2010.visits)) / SUM(imls2010.visits) * 100, 1) AS pct_change_in_visits
FROM imls_regions AS imlsreg INNER JOIN imls_library_survey_2016 AS imls2016
ON imlsreg.obereg = imls2016.obereg
INNER JOIN imls_library_survey_2010 AS imls2010
ON imlsreg.obereg = imls2010.obereg
WHERE imls2016.visits >= 0 AND imls2010.visits >= 0
GROUP BY imlsreg.obereg, imlsreg.obereg_name
ORDER BY pct_change_in_visits ASC;
```

Comment: Can you provide some additional information about the `imls2010.visits` and `imls2016.visits` columns? What are the types of those columns? Is there a reason you are casting the 2016 visits column `AS decimal(10,1)` but not the 2010 column?

Comment: The imls2016.visits and imls2010.visits are of integer data types and represents the numbers of visits made to a library the course of the year. My reason for casting imls2016.visits is to a the remainder of the division as decimal and not an integer which only returns the whole number divisible by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem. My sum value had a precision that was more than 10 (meaning that the sum which when still in integer format had a length of 12 values) hence when casting it throws a Numeric field overflow error. To find out where I went wrong I removed the ROUND() AND CAST() functions in listing 1.1:

- listing 1.1:

```
SELECT imlsreg.obereg,
        imlsreg.obereg_name,
        SUM(imls2016.visits) AS total_visits_2016,
        SUM(imls2010.visits) AS total_visits_2010,
        (SUM(imls2016.visits) - SUM(imls2010.visits)) / SUM(imls2010.visits) * 100 AS pct_change_in_visits
FROM imls_regions AS imlsreg INNER JOIN imls_library_survey_2016 AS imls2016
ON imlsreg.obereg = imls2016.obereg
INNER JOIN imls_library_survey_2010 AS imls2010
ON imlsreg.obereg = imls2010.obereg
WHERE imls2016.visits >= 0 AND imls2010.visits >= 0
GROUP BY imlsreg.obereg, imlsreg.obereg_name
ORDER BY pct_change_in_visits ASC;
```

This gave me the sum of visits I wanted to see but ignore the pct_change for now (most of the pct_change is 0 because dividing an two integers in sql gives you an integer hence it is important to cast an operating value to be a decimal or double precision numeric data-type)

[image: listing 1.1 results]

After counting the number of length of the max visits value (12 in length) I was able to find an accurate precision value. I then reverted to my previous code and adjusted the precision to numeric (14, 1). See code in listing 1.2:

- Listing 1.2:

```
SELECT imlsreg.obereg,
        imlsreg.obereg_name,
        SUM(imls2016.visits) AS total_visits_2016,
        SUM(imls2010.visits) AS total_visits_2010,
        ROUND((CAST(SUM(imls2016.visits) AS decimal(14, 1)) - SUM(imls2010.visits)) / SUM(imls2010.visits) * 100, 2) AS pct_change_in_visits
FROM imls_regions AS imlsreg INNER JOIN imls_library_survey_2016 AS imls2016
ON imlsreg.obereg = imls2016.obereg
INNER JOIN imls_library_survey_2010 AS imls2010
ON imlsreg.obereg = imls2010.obereg
WHERE imls2016.visits >= 0 AND imls2010.visits >= 0
GROUP BY imlsreg.obereg, imlsreg.obereg_name
ORDER BY pct_change_in_visits ASC;
```

[image: listing 1.2]

Answer (score 2):

When you cast to `decimal(10,1)`, you are reducing the range of allowable values of `SUM(imls2016.visits)` in exchange for greater precision, but this is causing your result to overflow.

There are two things you can do:

1. Perform the cast **after** you compute `SUM(imls2016.visits) - SUM(imls2010.visits)`
2. Reduce the precision of the cast.

Implementing the first one may suffice, and you would define `pct_change_in_visits` as:

```
ROUND(CAST(SUM(imls2016.visits) - SUM(imls2010.visits) AS decimal(10, 1)) / SUM(imls2010.visits) * 100, 1) AS pct_change_in_visits
```